# MySQL - read system timezone as the serverTimeZone

Tags: java, mysql, timezone

when I upgraded the mysql-connector-java from 5.1.35 to 8.0.21, we found some timezone issue.

**Mysql timezone setting:**

```
mysql> SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.time_zone | @@SESSION.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| UTC                | UTC                 |
+--------------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

**our application server timezone setting**

```
cat /etc/timezone
America/Chicago
```

is there any smart way to set this serverTimezone? such as read system timezone instead of the connection string.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=America/Chicago
```

Comment: You usually want the database to be in a server agnostic timezone like UTC.

Comment: When you say *"our server timezone"*, are you referring to the database server or the application server?

Comment: @Andreas, Thank you for your comment, I changed the desc to "our application server timezone".